# How to get the date trimmed of exactly in the format of (dd/mm/yyyy) in the following implementation of my code using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to get the date trimmed of exactly in the format of (dd/mm/yyyy) in the following implementation of my code using JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function disptextbox() {
        var d = new Date();

        var x = document.getElementById("ddlweeklist").value;
        switch (x)
         {
            case "1":
                document.getElementById("txtstart").value = d.toDateString();
                document.getElementById("Txtend").value = d.toDateString();
                break;
            case "2":
                var firstday = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay()));
                var lastday = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 6));
                document.getElementById("txtstart").value= firstday.toDateString();
                document.getElementById("Txtend").value = lastday.toDateString();
                break;

            case "3":
                var date = new Date();

                var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
                var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
                document.getElementById("txtstart").value = firstDay.toDateString();
                document.getElementById("Txtend").value = lastDay.toDateString();
                break;

            case "4":
                var firstd = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
                var lastd = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
                document.getElementById("txtstart").value = firstd.toDateString();
                document.getElementById("Txtend").value = lastd.toDateString();
                break;
        }
    }

</script>
```

in this code of implementation I want the date format to be in dd/mm/yyyy format ...I will be glad if any one help me over this this function call occurs on the drop down change especially...I am ok with functionality of the code but not comfortable in handling with DATE FUNCTIONS...
so please suggest me where I can get good examples for implementing date functions...in javascript

Comment: Show the date value that you are extracting from,to this particular format dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want dd/mm/yyyy format date:

```
new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10).replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g,"$3/$2/$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this function:

```
function toDateString(mydate) {
    var day = mydate.getDate();
    var month = mydate.getMonth();
    day = day < 10 ? '0'+day : day;
    month = month < 10 ? '0'+month : month;
    return day + '/' + month + '/' + mydate.getYear();
}
```

You could then use it this way:

```
alert(toDateString(firstday)); // I'm using alert just for demonstration purposes
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f9QQ3/)** you could fiddle with.

**EDITED:** Learning from @Helpful's answer below, my above function could be used as a `prototype` to better fit the way you wrote up your code like this:

```
Date.prototype.toDateString=function() {
    var day = this.getDate();
    var month = this.getMonth();
    day = day < 10 ? '0'+day : day;
    month = month < 10 ? '0'+month : month;
    return day + '/' + month + '/' + this.getYear();
}
```

so you could call it this way:

```
alert(thedate.toDateString()); // This is how you used it, if I understood it well.
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f9QQ3/1/)** of that.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a couple of prototypes for dates than you may find useful:

```
Date.prototype.dateStr=function(split){
    split=split===undefined?"-":split;
    var output=parseInt(parseInt(this.getMonth())+1).toString().toLength(2);
    output+=split;
    output+=this.getDate().toString().toLength(2);
    output+=split;
    output+=this.getFullYear().toString().toLength(4);
    return output;
}
Date.prototype.FOM=function(){
    return new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),1);
}
String.prototype.toLength=function(len,fill){
    fill=fill===undefined?"0":fill;
    var outStr=this.toString();
    while (outStr.length<parseInt(len)){
        outStr=fill+outStr;
    }
    return outStr;
}
```

Technically, the 3rd one is a string prototype, but whatever.  `new Date().FOM()` will give you a javascript date object for the first day of whatever month you pass it.  `new Date().dateStr("/")` will give you a string - mm/dd/yyyy format - with separators as whatever you pass it, default "-".

That last one will take a string and make it a certain length by prepending the 'fill' - default '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Pass any data format

```
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

hope this will help you sure.....